# Displaying `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` inside the environment verbatim

Tags: verbatim

I would like to display `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` inside the environment verbatim like in the folowing piece of code. Is it possible ?

```
\begin{verbatim}
Bla, bla,
\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}
Bla, bla,...
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Any reasons why you have to use `verbatim`, could you use the `listings` package instead?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the `verbatim` package then define your own variant

```
\newenvironment{myverbatim}%
{\verbatim}%
{\endverbatim}
```

then you can use `myverbatim` if you want to have literal `\end{verbatim}`

```
\begin{myverbatim}
Bla, bla,
\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}
Bla, bla,...
\end{myverbatim}
```

Comment: So simple... Sorry for my to-easy-to-solve-question...