# typing \end{verbatim}

Tags: verbatim

I am preparing a presentation in which I want to display the following as it is

```
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
```

For this I used

```
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}
```

But the first `\end{verbatim}` ends the environment and the second induces error. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

I should appreciate the explanation of the trick and commands suggested.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51031/displaying-beginverbatim-endverbatim-inside-the-environment-verbatim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\verb+\begin{verbatim} foo \end{verbatim}+
```

or, if you want it on separate lines

```
\verb+\begin{verbatim}+\\
\verb+foo+\\
\verb+\end{verbatim}+
```

or, if foo is long,

```
\verb+\begin{verbatim}+
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
\verb+\end{verbatim}+
```

Answer (score 15):

You can create a new environment that ensembles the verbatim environment, like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{realverbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}
Test of the new \verb~verbatim~ environment:

\begin{realverbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
\end{realverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there is any really sensible trick which will work with `verbatim` directly. I would use another verbatim-like environment from the `listings` or the `fancyvrb` package.