# remove double spacing inside {verbatim}

Tags: verbatim, line-spacing

I'm using the `uwthesis` class which generally typesets with a lot of
space between lines.  This is generally fine, however, I want to override
the spacing in certain examples which appear in the `verbatim` environment.

An MWE looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{uwthesis}
\begin{document}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{verbatim}
These
lines
are
also
doublespaced
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'd like to define a custom verbatim for use in examples
which presents text without the extra space between the lines, but I'm 
not sure what I need to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the `verbatim` font to use a different `\linespread`. More specifically, include `\linespread{1}` as part of `\verbatim@font`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{uwthesis}% http://ctan.org/pkg/uwthesis
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\linespread{1}\normalfont\ttfamily}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{verbatim}
These
lines
are
not
doublespaced
\end{verbatim}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines
\end{document}
```

The [`uwthesis` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/uwthesis) relies on the default LaTeX kernel `verbatim` environment, hence the ease of not having to add extra packages to obtain a desired output. For a reference to `\linespread`, see [Why doesn’t `\linespread` work?](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespread) on the TeX FAQ.

You could contain the redefinition in a macro that would act as a switch:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nextverbatimspread}[1]{%
  \def\verbatim@font{%
    \linespread{#1}\normalfont\ttfamily% Updated definition
    \gdef\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}}% Revert to old definition
}
\makeatother
```

which you could use in the form

```
\nextverbatimspread{1}
\begin{verbatim}
% ...single-spaced verbatim
\end{verbatim}
% ...some other content
\begin{verbatim}
% ...double-spaced verbatim
\end{verbatim}
```

---

For creating your own `verbatim`-like environment is a little more tricky. The easiest would be to include the [`verbatim` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) and use [David's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51031/5764) of wrapping the `verbatim` environment in command-form:

[image]

```
\documentclass{uwthesis}% http://ctan.org/pkg/uwthesis
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nextverbatimspread}[1]{%
  \def\verbatim@font{%
    \linespread{#1}\normalfont\ttfamily% Updated definition
    \gdef\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}}% Revert to old definition
}
\newenvironment{myverbatim}[1][1.5]
  {\def\verbatim@font{%
     \linespread{#1}\normalfont\ttfamily% Updated definition
     \gdef\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}}% Revert to old definition
   \verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\nextverbatimspread{1}
\begin{verbatim}
These
lines
are
not
doublespaced
\end{verbatim}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{myverbatim}
These
lines
are
doublespaced
\end{myverbatim}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{myverbatim}[1]
These
lines
are
not
doublespaced
\end{myverbatim}
\end{document}
```

The `myverbatim` environment takes an option argument to specify a modified `\linespread`. The default is `1.5`, as specified by [`uwthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/uwthesis) ("not quite doublespaced", according to [`uwthesis.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/uwthesis/uwthesis.cls), line 158).

Comment: I like this answer as it avoids loading more packages.  I'd like to use this technique to define a customized {verbatim}, say {verbatim1}, that has this property.  I have some other text in my document that I think I'd like to keep as normal verbatim.  To do that, I'd need some sort of \newcommand, but I'm not sure exactly what to write.

Comment: @apexofservice: `verbatim` is notoriously picky. I've added an update to my answer that achieves what you're after, but requires the [`verbatim` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim).

Comment: Is your first solution compatible with `fontspec`? For example, to reduce the size of the verbatim font, I found this to work: `\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Droid Sans Mono}`, but it's ignored in the `verbatim` environment when I use your `\def\verbatim@font{...}` bit above. I'm not sure how to combine the two if it's possible...

Answer (score 10):

Look at using `fancyvrb`.  It has a lot of nice tricks.  But in particular, you can set the baselineskip within the verbatim environment:

```
\documentclass{uwthesis}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{Verbatim}[baselinestretch=0.75]
These
lines
are
also
doublespaced
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

`0.75` might be a bit tight for you.

[image]

Comment: I'll try this solution as it seems to avoid redefining the old {verbatim} (so that I can have some examples which still have doublespacing).

Comment: You can also say `\fvset{baselinestretch=1}` in the preamble, thus avoiding the need to type it every time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to change `\baselinestretch` from `1.5` (the default in `uwthesis.cls`) to `1`:

```
\documentclass{uwthesis}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\def\baselinestretch{1}}

\begin{document}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\begin{verbatim}
These
lines
are
not
doublespaced
\end{verbatim}

Double \\
Spaced \\
Lines

\end{document}
```

[image]